# How to handle if DbTransaction's Commit() or Rollback() throw exception?

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions

I am working with Visual Studio 2012 and MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

In my code I am using `DbConnection` and `DbTransaction`. This is my code:

```
DbConnection dbConnection = null;
DbTransaction dbTransaction = null;

try
{
   dbConnection = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient").CreateConnection();
   dbConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
   dbConnection.Open();
   dbTransaction = dbConnection.BeginTransaction();
   // do my work using dbConnection and dbTransaction
   dbTransaction.Commit();
} 
catch (MyWorkFailedException mwfe)
{
   dbTransaction.Rollback();
   throw;
}
finally
{
   if (dbConnection != null)
   {
      dbConnection.Close();
      dbConnection.Dispose();
   }
}
```

Is it possible that `dbTransaction.Commit();` or `dbTransaction.Rollback();` throws an exception?

If yes then how to handle it in my code? How c# programmers usually handles this situation? Or they dont handle this situation?

Comment: Why there's not a single `using` in your code?

Comment: @SergRogovtsev is not the way I am using `try finally` same as using `using` for `DbConnection`? If yes then it is just a preference and old habbit.

Comment: It's mostly the same, but you can make mistakes easily (for example, in your code you could try to rollback a nonexistent transaction). `using` is good pattern you should leverage.

Comment: @sergRogovtsev "using is good pattern you should leverage" -> not always in case of WCF client (known bug) should you wrap it within try catch finnaly to handle the dispose explicitly

Comment: @bet, this is not a WCF client.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, both `Commit` and `Rollback` ***can*** throw exceptions. However, these should probably be propagated up and either logged or displayed as an error to the user. How you want to handle the error is entirely up to you, but typically the errors will be due to a closed connection. Secondly, you should leverage `using`

```
using (var dbConnection  = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.SqlClient").CreateConnection())
{
    dbConnection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    dbConnection.Open();
    using (var dbTransaction = dbConnection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        //Do work here

        dbTransaction.Commit();
    }
}
```

`DbTransaction` will automatically rollback on its dispose method (assuming it hasn't been committed). Exceptions thrown by this code ***typically*** are not  something you can gracefully handle. For the most part, they would come from SQL errors (invalid syntax, FK errors, etc), or a closed connection.

As long as you've got a good logging system in place, the above code should be all you need.

Comment: Why do you need this rather than the clear `new SqlConnection()`?

Comment: I do need to propagate up exceptions and display as an error to the user. I made the change in my code above to throw `MyWorkFailedException` again after rollback. Assume I have a custom exception `InfrastructureException`; how would you throw this exception in your code if  commit or rollback failed?

Answer (score 2):

Use `TransactionScope` instead which has only `Complete()`. Once it has been disposed it will rollback the underlying transaction. Any exception will cause the underlying transaction to be rolledback as well:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    // do stuff

    scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: I thought `TransactionScope` is only needed if your transaction span multiple databases?

Comment: Actually not, it works with any compliant provider, and its somewhat cleaner than using `DbTransaction`s

Answer (score 1):

You handle the exception in any of the methods (both `Commit` and `Rollback`) as failure in transaction. If you want/have to, you can clean up something in your C# code. Database cleanup will be handled automatically (at least, for ACID-compliant DB).

Comment: The one in Rob's answer will do.